# I need insert in DIV the result of append jquery, simply css not work well

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, append

This is a extract of my html page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"> 
<title>jQuery Mobile Docs - Radio Buttons</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/css/themes/default/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css" /> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function insert(){
    var myradio="<input type='radio' name='radio-1' id='radio-choice-2' value='radio-choice-2' /><label for='radio-choice-2'>Tiger</label>";
    $("#space").html(myradio);
}
</script>
</head> 
<body onLoad="insert()"> 
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <legend>Choose :</legend>
                  <input type="radio" name='radio-1' id='radio-choice-1' value="radio-choice-1"  />
                  <label for="radio-choice-1">Cat</label>

                  <div id="space"></div>

                  <input type="radio" name='radio-1' id='radio-choice-3' value="radio-choice-3"  />
                  <label for="radio-choice-3">Dog</label>
            </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /content -->
    </div><!-- /page -->
</body>
```

In my example, the first and third radio check show perfectly style css, but second radio check not work or not show style css. Why?

Comment: Could you show us the related css rules?

Answer (score 2):

created a fiddle.you are appending html .but not creating the button in jquery mobile

```
$("#space").append(myradio).trigger("create");
```

check this working fiddle
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/quKMd/)

Comment: Trigger("create") isn't always the solution. Each widget has it's own way of enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

After you append radio button or checkbox, enhance them manually by calling `.checkboxradio();`

```
$("#radio-choice-2").checkboxradio();
```

**Note**: Remove `jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css`. You only need it when you use custom themes created by ThemeRoller.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/3RDuc/)**